# using regex to fix markdown input - link labels

Tags: python, regex, markdown

We've run into a problem with some markdown content.  A few jquery editors we used did not write proper markdown syntax.  Embedded Links used the 'label' format, which drops the links at the bottom of the document ( Just like the StackOverflow editor ).   The problem we encountered, is that the links were sometimes formatted in a non-standard way.  While they were allowed to be prefixed with 0,3 spaces, some came in at 4 spaces (You might notice that StackOverflow forces 2 spaces in javascript) -- which triggers it as `preformatted text` in markdown parsers.

As a quick example:

```
This is a sample doucument that would have inline links. 
[Example 0][0], [Example 1][1], [Example 2][2] , [Example 3][3] , [Example 4][4]

[0]: http://example.com
 [1]:      http://example.com/1
  [2] : http://example.com/2
   [3]: http://example.com/3
    [4]  : http://example.com/4
```

I'm wanting to reformat this last section into proper markdown:

```
[0]: http://example.com
[1]: http://example.com/1
[2]: http://example.com/2
[3]: http://example.com/3
[4]: http://example.com/4
```

I'm running into a wall trying to come up with the right regex to catch the 'labels' section.  I can grab the labels within the section fine -- but the section is eluding me.

Here's what I have so far:

```
RE_footnote = re.compile("""
    (?P<labels_section>
        ^[\t\ ]*$                             ## we must start with an empty line
        \s+                       
        (?P<labels>
            (?P<a_label>
                ^
                    [\ \t]*                     ## we could have 0-n spaces or tabs
                    \[                          ## BRACKET - open
                        (?P<id>
                            [^^\]]+
                        )
                    \]                          ## BRACKET - close
                    \s*
                    :                           ## COLON
                    \s*
                    (?P<link>                   ## WE want anything here
                        [^$]+
                    )
                $
            )+                                  ## multiple labels
        )
    )
""",re.VERBOSE|re.I|re.M)
```

The specific problems I have:

1. I can't figure out how to allow for 1 or more "blank lines".  This triggers an invalid regex with nothing to repeat:

   (?:                  ## wrap it in a non-capturing group, require 1+ occurances
        ^[\t\ ]*$
   )+
2. The match won't work without a whitespace match before the  group `\s+`.  I can't figure out what/why.
3. I want this to match at the END of the document only , to ensure we're only fixing these javascript errors ( and not something at the core of the document ).  all my attempts to work a `\z` into this have failed, miserably.

can anyone offer some advice?

---

updated

this works:

```
RE_MARKDOWN_footnote = re.compile("""
    (?P<labels_section>
        (?:                            ## we must start with an empty / whitepace-only line
            ^\s*$
        )                              
        \s*                             ## there can be more whitespace lines
        (?P<labels>
            (?P<a_label>
                ^
                    [\ \t]*                     ## we could have 0-n spaces or tabs
                    \[                          ## BRACKET - open
                        (?P<id>
                            [^^\]]+
                        )
                    \]                          ## BRACKET - close
                    \s*
                    :                           ## COLON
                    \s*
                    (?P<link>                   ## WE want anything here
                        [^$]+
                    )
                $
            )+                                  ## multiple labels
        )
        \s*                                     ## we might have some empty lines 
        \Z                                      ## ensure the end of document
    )
""",re.VERBOSE|re.I|re.M)
```

Comment: someone who comments their regex??  what is this sorcery?! :)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but `\t` matches tabs, not blank lines. I think you might be looking for `\n`?

Comment: So general thing: whenever I'm using regex, I try to restrict the domain of what I'm regex-ing as much as possible.  Like here: is it possible to start at the end of your string and look backwards for `'[0]'`, slice that out, regex-sanitize, splice back in?  That seems like a much easier problem to solve and will result in actually maintainable code.

Comment: `^[\t\ ]*$` should match a line with a variable amount of spaces or tabs in it -- shouldn't it?.  i can't trust that it will be a newline.

Comment: @roippi markdown labels can be numeric or text based; unless i'm reading your question wrong, that strategy isn't likely to be easier

Comment: Wouldn't `\s*` match any number of blank lines (in conjunction with the `re.M` flag)? And for question 2, remember that a `$` doesn't actually match the newline, but the location just before the newline, so that's why you need to still match the newline after it.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco Right.  Well, replace searching for `[0]` with whatever heuristic you'd like.  Still seems worthwhile to me, once you separate out that section the `re.sub` operation is *really* straightforward.

Comment: The replacement part is already easy, and handled by a simpler regex.   It's just ensuring that I'm getting this at the tail-end of the document, where I'm reasonably assured this format correlates to a label.  This could potentially be actual content if it's earlier in the string.

Comment: @ooga thanks for the reminder.  playing around with things, it seems my `\z` wasn't matching because i used a lowercase(z) and not an uppercase(Z).  i think i almost have this.

Comment: This `[^$]+` doesn't make any sense. What could it mean?

Comment: `[^$]+` = all chars except a line end. within the brackets, `^` is the negation character, not line start.

Comment: Maybe `[^\n]+` is what you want then.

Comment: made some changes based on all the comments.  it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started from scratch; is there a reason something simpler like this couldn't work?

```
^\s*                # beginning of the line; may include whitespace
  \[                # opening bracket
     (?P<id>\d+)    # our ID
  \]                # closing bracket
\s*                 # optional whitespace
  :                 # colon
\s*                 # optional whitespace
  (?P<link>[^\n]+)  # our link is everything up to a new line
$                   # end of the line
```

This was done using the global and multi-line modifiers, `gm`.  Replace matches with: `[\id]: \link`.  Here is a working example: http://regex101.com/r/mM8dI2

Comment: You made my change! :-) (Just glad to have added something to the convo.)

Comment: Yes, props to @ooga for the `[^\n]+`.  I originally used a much grosser lazy matching `[^$]+?`.

Comment: I actually thought the dollar sign wouldn't work at all. I was testing it in perl, though, and it complained about an "unmatched [ in regex" for `[^$]+`.

Comment: I needed to peg it to the bottom of the document, ending it on `\Z`. there are a handful of ideas in here that could probably work , others that wont ( the id is not necessarily numeric, etc )

Comment: The reason it doesn't work at first is since `+` is greedy and goes all the way to the last `[^$]` which is the last character in the last line.  Making it lazy causes it to go to the first `[^$]` which is the last character in the current line.

Comment: It sounds like you got it to work, though, right @JonathanVanasco?

Comment: yeah, it works. but it's ugly.  there are lots of things that could be improved (performance, readability).  without you and @ooga it would not be working.

the ugly code passes all my tests, so i'm running it on legacy content right now.  i'll clean it up later this week with some ideas from your code, and probably integrate that as a filter or validator.

Comment: rewrote the test suite when some errors popped up on the legacy content.  a slightly reworked version of yours was doing better than mine -- so thanks a ton!  If you're interested, here's the test that I wrote -- https://gist.github.com/jvanasco/8919972 .  I had ended up matching a false positive that I wasn't testing for correctly (now am), so I ditched it for yours.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you want, feel free to edit my answer to include what ultimately ended up working for you (since I know you had to change some things).